# Displaying global variable from .js external lib

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I added some external libs to my ionic project.

In one of them i have declared `var loading = false;`

In my page .ts file, i'm "importing" that variable, using:

```
declare var loading;
```

Now, I can use this variable in functions, etc., but there is problem with displaying, i can't display it in page .html like that:

```
{{ loading }}
```

Also , i tried to use function, to return this variable (`public load = function(){return loading;}`), but its not working correctly - sometimes when variable is changing (automatically), my page is not detecting it, and text is not changing.

Is there any way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a component variable and on init assign your global variable to your local component variable.

Comment: Not exactly, cus global variable can be changed by .js lib (automatically), so i need to watch global variable all time

Comment: Then I guess you need to create a behavior subject in a service that watches this variable change then you can subscribe to it in your component.

Comment: How can i do it? Can you give any example
?

Comment: Depends on the library which one is it?